# Haskell inheriting type classes

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class P a where
  nameOf :: a -> String
```

I would like to declare that all instances of this class are automatically instances of `Show`. My first attempt would be the following:

```
instance P a => Show a where
  show = nameOf
```

My first attempt to go this way yesterday resulted in a rabbit warren of language extensions: I was first told to switch on flexible instances, then undecidable instances, then overlapping instances, and finally getting an error about overlapping instance declarations. I gave up and returned to repeating the code. However, this fundamentally seems like a very simple demand, and one that should be easily satisfied.

So, two questions:

1. Is there a trivially easy way to do this that I've just missed?
2. Why do I get an overlapping instances problem? I can see why I might need `UndecidableInstances`, since I seem to be violating the Paterson condition, but there are no overlapping instances around here: there are no instances of `P`, even. Why does the typechecker believe there are multiple instances for `Show Double` (as seems to be the case in this toy example)?

Comment: The overlap (and overloading resolution) is determined by just the instance head `Show a`, so it does indeed overlap with every other `Show` instance.

Comment: Suppose you declare instance of `P Int` and you already had an instance for `Show Int` so this will result in overlapping instances for Show.

Comment: @Satvik Sure, except that I don't have an instance of `P Int` around. I would expect an error if I tried to create a `P Int`, but not by merely declaring that it could exist.

Comment: @augustss Huh, that's a little annoying. Oh well.

Comment: @Impredicative Yes, it is annoying.  But that's how Haskell overloading resolution works.  You could easily imagine a more sophisticated algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the overlapping instances error because some of your instances of `P` may have other instances of `Show` and then the compiler won't be able to decide which ones to use. If you have an instance of `P` for `Double`, then there you go, you get two instances of `Show` for `Double`: yours general one and the one already declared in Haskell's base library. How this error is triggered is correctly stated by @augustss in the comments to your question. For more info see [the specs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-overlap).

As you already know, there is no way to achieve what you're trying without the `UndecidableInstances`. When you enable that flag you must understand that you're taking over the compiler's responsibility to ensure that there won't arise any conflicting instances. This means that, of course, there mustn't be any other instances of `Show` produced in your library. This also means that your library won't export the `P` class, which will erase the possibility of users of the library declaring the conflicting instances.

If your case somehow conflicts with the said above, it's a reliable sign of that there must be something wrong with it. And in fact there is...

---

What you're trying to achieve is incorrect above all. You are missing several important points about the `Show` typeclass, distinguishing it from constructs like a `toString` method of popular OO languages:

1. From [Show's haddock](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aShow):

   > The result of show is a syntactically correct Haskell expression containing only constants, given the fixity declarations in force at the point where the type is declared. It contains only the constructor names defined in the data type, parentheses, and spaces. When labelled constructor fields are used, braces, commas, field names, and equal signs are also used.

   In other words, declaring an instance of `Show`, which does not produce a valid Haskell expression, is incorrect per se.
2. Given the above it just doesn't make sense to declare a custom instance of `Show` when the type allows to simply derive it.
3. When a type does not allow to derive it (e.g., GADT), generally you'll still have to stick to type-specific instances to produce correct results.

So, if you need a custom representation function, you shouldn't use `Show` for that. Just declare a custom class, e.g.:

```
class Repr a where
  repr :: a -> String
```

and approach the instances declaration responsibly.

Comment: I'm wary to accept this answer because I feel it's technically wrong in part. The problem is not that some instances of `P` have other instances of `Show`: as noted, there *are* no instances of `P`. `augustss` has explained the true issue, being to do with how the overlap is evaluated. If you fix that, I'd be happy to accept; I take your point about the use of 'show'.

Comment: @Impredicative Probably I didn't make myself clear, I've updated the first paragraph.